# JTabbedPane not switching tab contents

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtabbedpane

I'm having an issue with JTabbedPane, in that the contents of individual tabs aren't showing up (Every time I click a new tab, the active tab changes but the contents do not, so I see the same content no matter which tab is selected.).

I'm trying to write an IDE for my own programming language, but have never worked with JTabbedPane before. My tabbed pane consists of JEditTextArea's (user-written component) housed in JScrollPanes. Here is the responsible class

```
package tide.editor;

import javax.swing.*;

import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.syntax.jedit.*;
import org.syntax.jedit.tokenmarker.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Editor extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

//Version ID
final static String VERSION = "0.01a";

//The editor pane houses the JTabbedPane that allows for code editing
//JPanel editorPane;

JTabbedPane tabbedPanel;

//The JTextPanes hold the source for currently open programs
ArrayList<JEditTextArea> textPanes;

//The toolbar that allows for quick opening, saving, compiling etc
JToolBar toolBar;

//Buttons for the toolbar
JButton newButton, openButton, saveButton, compileButton, runButton;


public Editor()
{
    super("tIDE v" + VERSION);
    setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    init();
    setVisible(true);
    textPanes.get(0).requestFocus();
}

public void init()
{
    //Initialise toolbar
    toolBar = new JToolBar();
    toolBar.setFloatable(false);

    newButton = new JButton("New");
    newButton.addActionListener(this);
    openButton = new JButton("Open");
    openButton.addActionListener(this);
    saveButton = new JButton("Save");
    saveButton.addActionListener(this);
    compileButton = new JButton("Compile");
    compileButton.addActionListener(this);
    runButton = new JButton("Run");
    runButton.addActionListener(this);

    toolBar.add(newButton);
    toolBar.add(openButton);
    toolBar.add(saveButton);
    toolBar.add(compileButton);
    toolBar.add(runButton);


    tabbedPanel = new JTabbedPane();

    textPanes = new ArrayList<JEditTextArea>();

    JEditTextArea initialProgram = createTextArea("program.t");

        tabbedPanel.addTab(initialProgram.getName(), new JScrollPane(initialProgram));


    getContentPane().add(tabbedPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(toolBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        new Editor();
    }
});

}

JEditTextArea createTextArea(String name)
{
    JEditTextArea editPane = new JEditTextArea(name);
    editPane.setTokenMarker(new TTokenMarker());

    textPanes.add(editPane);

    return editPane;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() == newButton)
    {
        String filename = "program2";
        boolean fileExists = true;

        //Ensures that no duplicate files are created
        while (fileExists)
        {
        fileExists = false;
        //Get new file name from user
        filename = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a name for the file", "program.t");

        //Cancel was clicked in the new file dialog
        if (filename == null)
            return;

            for (JEditTextArea panes: textPanes)
            {
                if (panes.getName().equals(filename) || panes.getName().equals(filename.concat(".t")) || panes.getName().concat(".t").equals(filename))
                    fileExists = true;
            }
        }

        //add extension if it is missing
        if(!filename.endsWith(".t"))
            filename = filename.concat(".t");

        //Add the new "file" to the editor window in a new tab
        tabbedPanel.addTab(filename, new JScrollPane(createTextArea(filename)));
        tabbedPanel.setSelectedIndex(tabbedPanel.getSelectedIndex()+1);
    }

    if (e.getSource() == openButton)
    {
        File f = null;


        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Choose target file location");
        fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                "t source or bytecode(.t, .tbc)", "t", "tbc");

        fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);

        if (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            f = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        }

        //Cancel button was clicked on the open file dialog
        if (f == null)
            return;

        //Load the contents of the selected file into the editor
        else
        {
            JEditTextArea textArea = null;
            StringBuilder inputText = null;

            try {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);

                //Add a new text area to the editor
                textArea = createTextArea(f.getName());
                tabbedPanel.add(new JScrollPane(textArea), textArea.getName());

                //The newly added tab is set as the active tab
                tabbedPanel.setSelectedIndex(tabbedPanel.getTabCount()-1);
                textArea.requestFocus();

                inputText = new StringBuilder();
                while (sc.hasNext())
                {
                    inputText.append(sc.nextLine() + "\n");
                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            //Set the contents of the current text area to that of the opened file
            textArea.setText(inputText.toString());
        }
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

1) remove code lines from `FileIO` related `try - catch` blok

```
textArea = createTextArea(f.getName());
tabbedPanel.add(new JScrollPane(textArea), textArea.getName());
//The newly added tab is set as the active tab
tabbedPanel.setSelectedIndex(tabbedPanel.getTabCount()-1);
textArea.requestFocus();
```

prepare those `Object` before of after `Input / OutputStreams`

2) `close()` all `Objects` from `Input / OutputStreams`, in the `finally` block (`try - catch - finally`)

3) `JTextComponets` implements `read()` and `write()`, accepting all separators, then there no reason programatically call for "\n"

4) use `SwingWorker` code for `FileIO`

Comment: I've tried most of what you've suggested here (I don't know how to use SwingWorker) but still no luck.

Comment: @Peter: Please read up on SwingWorker in the tutorials. I fear your problem may be a concurrency issue.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be solution for the root cause, but there might be some inconsistency in your code which is causing paint issues on the TestAreas, So I would suggest you to register a TabChageListener and then repaint the ScrollPane for that specific tab, this should work:

```
tabbedPanel.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
     int selectedIndex =   tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex();
  // get the ScrollPane for this selectedIndex and then repaint it.

    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work unfortunately. Same problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this very problem for the last couple of hours.

In fact, it doesn't matter how many `JEditTextArea` you instantiate, they all rely on the same `SyntaxDocument`, thus the same text. That's just the way it's coded in `JEditTextArea`.

In constructor `public JEditTextArea(TextAreaDefaults defaults)` you will need to find the line:

> `setDocument(defaults.document);`

and replace it with:

> setDocument(new SyntaxDocument());

and it will instantiate a brand new `Document` every time you make a new `JEditTextArea`.